# Excel VBA How to enable or disable checkboxes based on certain conditions by using vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to code in VBA to enable or disable the checkboxes for the mobile plan based on the brand selected as shown in the image.

[image]

The table on the left acts as an indicator of the availability of the mobile plans for the respective brands as indicated by `"Y"` or `"N"`. For example, when the user selected `"Apple"` from the dropdown list, he is only allowed to tick the `Mobile Plan 1`.

The attempted solution is based on only one criteria, which is for `"Apple"` in this case. How do I enhance the coding so that when the user selects `"Samsung"`, the status of the checkboxes will change accordingly?

I planned to declare a variable as an `Integer` to act as an column indicator (for eg, `Apple = 2, Samsung = 3, Nokia = 4`)  and pass this integer to the each function `"CheckBox_Change"` and use the `VLOOKUP` function, but I get an error message:

> "procedure declaration does not match description of event or
>   procedure having the same name"

while I was trying to do so.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$G$1" Then

CheckBox1.Value = False
CheckBox2.Value = False
CheckBox3.Value = False

Call CheckBox1_Change
Call CheckBox2_Change
Call CheckBox3_Change    
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()

If Range("B3").Value = "Y" Then
    CheckBox1.Enabled = True
Else
    CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    CheckBox1.Value = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
    Range("H3").Value = ""
End If

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Change()

If Range("B4").Value = "Y" Then
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True
Else
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    CheckBox2.Value = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Change()

If Range("B5").Value = "Y" Then
    CheckBox3.Enabled = True
Else
    CheckBox3.Enabled = False
    CheckBox3.Value = False
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go this way (explanations in comments):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$G$1" Then
        With Range("B2:D2").Find(Target.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole) ' reference the cell with the proper Brand
            CheckBox1.Enabled = .Offset(1).Value = "Y" 'set checkbox visibility to match referenced cell column corresponding value
            CheckBox2.Enabled = .Offset(2).Value = "Y" ' same as above
            CheckBox3.Enabled = .Offset(3).Value = "Y" ' same as above
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

---

you could also loop between checkboxes "indexes" and avoid some code duplication:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$G$1" Then
        Dim i As Long
        With Range("B2:D2").Find(Target.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole) ' reference the cell with the proper Brand
            For i = 1 To 3 ' loop from 1 to 3 (number of checkboxes)
                Me.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Enabled = .Offset(i).Value = "Y" 'set current checkbox visibility to match referenced cell column corresponding value 
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Basing on @QHarr's answer, you can reduce the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "G1" Then
        Me.CheckBox1.Enabled = (Target = "Apple")
        Me.CheckBox2.Enabled = (Target = "Samsung")
        Me.CheckBox3.Enabled = (Target = "Samsung")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this solution would work for the "Y"/"N" values table as shown in OP's example. But it'd fail for any other different table values

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It uses Select Case to avoid repeating sections of code and having multiple subs.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "G1" Then

        Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Apple"
            Me.CheckBox1.Enabled = True
            Me.CheckBox2.Enabled = False
            Me.CheckBox3.Enabled = False
        Case "Samsung"
            Me.CheckBox1.Enabled = False
            Me.CheckBox2.Enabled = True
            Me.CheckBox3.Enabled = True
        Case Else
            Me.CheckBox1.Enabled = False
            Me.CheckBox2.Enabled = False
            Me.CheckBox3.Enabled = False
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this solution would work for the "Y"/"N" values table as shown in OP's example. But it'd fail for any other different table values